# Do you need to inoculate a mushroom growing medium before breaking it up to spread on the ground?

Tags: mushrooms, growing-medium

I saw most people grow mushrooms in a medium before breaking it up to put on the bigger growing medium, but I'm wondering if I can just mix molasses with water (came from a YouTube video), and the different spores from syringes in order to get a medium that I want to grow in order to propagate what I want to grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of using colonized substrate is that the mycelium has grown on a fairly cheap substrate and you know it's viable.

On the other hand, if you try to inoculate directly from spore syringes you are talking about a very expensive method of trying to inoculate the grow beds.  It will take longer as well as the spores have to mate with a neighbouring spore to then form the mycelial network.  And the longer time will provide more opportunities for other spores to contaminate your grow bed.